# Office.SeriesTime TypeScript definition is missing the Properties only has Methods

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Office.context.mailbox.item.recurrence.getAsync() returns an object but I'm unable to cast parts of it to other variables.
e.g. interface Office.SeriesTime only defines the GetXXX() methods

```
/**
 * Gets the duration in minutes of a usual instance in a recurring appointment series.
 * 
 * [Api set: Mailbox 1.7]
 *
 * @remarks
 * 
 * **{@link https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/understanding-outlook-add-in-permissions | Minimum permission level}**: `ReadItem`
 * 
 * **{@link https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-add-ins-overview#extension-points | Applicable Outlook mode}**: Compose or Read
 */
getDuration(): number;
```

e.g. This won't compile because interface Office.SeriesTime does not define the properties.

```
    const fixedRecurrence: Office.SeriesTime = recurrence.seriesTime;
    if (fixedRecurrence.endYear === 0) {
      fixedRecurrence.endYear = fixedEndDate.getFullYear();
      fixedRecurrence.endMonth = fixedEndDate.getMonth() + 1;
      fixedRecurrence.endDay = fixedEndDate.getDate();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See the [Office.SeriesTime interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.seriestime?view=outlook-js-preview) members. It seems you need to use the [getEndDate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.seriestime?view=outlook-js-preview#getEndDate__) method instead which allows to get the end date of a recurrence pattern in the following `ISO 8601` date format: `"YYYY-MM-DD"`.

```
// This example gets the end date of a recurring appointment series.
Office.context.mailbox.item.recurrence.getAsync(callback);

function callback(asyncResult) {
    var context = asyncResult.context;
    var recurrence = asyncResult.value;
    var endDate = recurrence.seriesTime.getEndDate();
}
```

Comment: IIt should not be necessary to use the getEndDate() method since the values are already present in the object. It's only because the TypeScript interface is missing the properties that one can't get the endYear, endMonth, and endDay values.  e.g. casting the seriesTime as any:  
    const s: any = recurrence.seriesTime;
    console.log(s.endYear); <br/>works fine

Comment: The property values on the SeriesTime object are internal values that are subject to change in name. The public facing values are those defined in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.seriestime?view=outlook-js-preview These values are not subject to change (without announcement). Using internal values could break your add-in without notice.